# What's the difference between computed "var" and a nullary function, and when should each be used?

Tags: swift

Swift allows both:

```
var foo: Int { return 1 }
func foo() -> Int { return 1 }
```

At the call site, these are used as:

```
bar.foo
bar.foo()
```

Advantages I see of `func`:

- It can be referred to as a closure capturing the receiver (`bar.foo` is permitted for any `() -> Int` parameter)
- It can be referred to a static member (`Bar.foo` is `Bar -> (() -> Int)`).

Advantages I see of `var`:

- Shorter, cleaner code (which isn't a *technical* difference).
- Compatible with `let` for protocol conformances - given a protocol `FooType`, `Bar` may conform with a computed `var`, but `Baz` might be able to get by with only a constant `let` declaration. This may also result in shorter code.

What are all of the differences and similarities of the two types of declaration?

Answer (score 0):

With `var` you can add other observers (default is `get` observer)

```
var foo: Int {
   get{
    return 1
   }
   set(v){
     self.something = v
     self.moreStuff()
   }
 }
```

allowing to set `bar.foo = 5`

`func` is just a method that can also return `void`  (nothing) when `var` will have a type